# Using Closed Projection in Spring Data JPA failed with MappingException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I try to get a subset of attributes from a JPA entity `Data` by using [interface-based Projection in Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) to minimize the JSON response data of an HTTP request from my frontend (Angular).

Using Closed Projection seems a good approach to handle that - simple to implement and easy to maintain.

```java
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {
    List<DataView> findByLocation(String location))

    interface DataView {
        String getLocation();
    }
}
```

I'm using `JpaRepository` to get the full scope of the Spring Data Repository functionality but I receive the following exception in my Tomcat console:

```log
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext.getRequiredPersistentEntity(MappingContext.java:79) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentEntities.getRequiredPersistentEntity(PersistentEntities.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:90) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toModel(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:73) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.entitiesToResources(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:110) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.AbstractRepositoryRestController.toCollectionModel(AbstractRepositoryRestController.java:80) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.lambda$toModel$1(RepositorySearchController.java:204) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.toModel(RepositorySearchController.java:201) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositorySearchController.executeSearch(RepositorySearchController.java:185) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
```

[I read that](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections#1-closed-projections) "Behind the scenes, Spring creates a proxy instance of the projection interface for each entity object, and all calls to the proxy are forwarded to that object."

What am I doing wrong here?

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit**

I've noticed that I get a CORS error 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' if the frontend request the URL. I assume that the response is some kind of cross origin. Is this caused by the proxy instance I pointed out before? That would be a really strange behaviour. I will try to add `cors.allowed.headers` to the dev tomcat instance and check that out.

**Result of applying CORS filter**

Same error as before if I add `http://localhost:8080` or `http://localhost:4200` to dev pr prod tomcat instance `web.xml`. I think, the proxy instance refers to another URL. Anyone has an idea?

```xml
<filter>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost:4200,http://localhost:8080</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: can you try changing the  `findById` method name to something else? `findById` method should return `Optional<Data>` per base class `CrudRepository`

Comment: I've changed it to `Optional<List<DataView>> findByLocation(@RequestParam("location") String location);` but it leads to  the same error.

Comment: I think it would be `List<DataView> findByLocation(String location);` but I don't think that's the cause of that stracktrace error

Comment: Looks like it's caused by a CORS error. Think, the proxy instance has some kind of cross origin mechanic and tomcat refuse the response. That's a strange behaviour.

Comment: you want jpa project right? and not spring data rest projection

Comment: I'm using spring data REST:
`public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
  // expose entity id
  config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(e -> e.getJavaType()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Class[0]));
 }`

Comment: I just noticed that there is a `CorsRegistry cors` parameter. Can I handle the CORS right here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241408/discussion-between-marcel-and-indybee).

Comment: I figured out that returning a single Closed Projection is working but not multiple Closed Projections like `Collection<DataView> findByLocation(String location)`. If I call `DataView findByLocation(String location)` it works fine. Even with the approach of DTO projection creating a DTO class to select a subset of attributes. All is getting down by returning an `Iterable` like `Collection` or `List` or whatever.

Comment: just re-reading your question, is your only goal to return less fields to angular ui, is it ok if the jpa query is still selecting all fields?

Comment: It seems Spring Data JPA is not able to return a projection in a response to the client out of the box. See here: [github.com](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1213) Sometimes, the JSON response is about 10MB which is pretty big imo. After subset maybe about 1/3. Right now, it's a nice-to-have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I understand what I did wrong...

Until yesterday, I just worked with GET requests which worked pretty fine only using Springs `@Repository` and `@SpringBootApplication`. Today, I started to handle POST requests which requires different mappings for the requests. Springs `@RestController` can handle that. In the [tutorial](https://progressivecoder.com/rest-api-using-spring-boot-insert-update/) the controller returns a class `ResponseEntity<T>` which actually handles the response of the request, different media types etc. by using full Spring MVC approach.

Closed projections and all DTO corresponding stuff are working just fine, now.

Nevertheless, thanks all for your time - especially @indybee!

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  spring-data-rest does support post methods as well, however I do think using @RestController (without spring-data-rest) provides more flexible options

Comment: I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` in my maven dependencies. As far as I know, it contains all relevant packages to run it as an independant project to deploy on an application server and serve as a REST service. Or is there any other subset of dependency which provides the same functionality?

Comment: From your answer, it sounded like you meant separate @RestController is needed to support the `post` method.  spring-data-rest also supports `post` (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro)

imho I find spring-data-rest somewhat restrictive though as supposed to just creating @RestController to call the jpa repository and usually just create @RestController for all get/post/put/patch/delete methods

Comment: Yes, the pure Spring Data REST is pretty limited especially when it comes to handle customized responses. I followed [this tutorial)](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) which covers almost everything about REST services. According to that and other sources, I have implemented RPC (with controller, service, DAO, DTO layers) which totally fits my needs (section: 'What makes something RESTful?'). With projections and without RESTful stuff, my project got a huge performance boost. Cheers, man! :)

Answer (score 1):

The class `Data` must be a JPA entity. I'm doubting that Data is just a normal DTO class. The ID of entity `Data` is of the type `Long` and the parameter `Integer` is used to query the entity. `@RequestParam` is used in a controller and it is not needed here. `findById` already exists in `CRUD` repository, it is not recommended to override it. It is better to use another method name. The repository name is `SensorDataRepository`, it means it is meant to manage the entity `SensorData` rather than the entity `Data`.

The repository and projection interface should look something like below.

```
public interface DataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, Long> {
    List<DataView> findDataViewById(Long id);

    interface DataView {
        Long getId(); // if the field name is `id`, the method name should be `getId()`
    }
}
```

Comment: I clarified your points by editing my question above. I changed it to `getLocation()`. Thanks for pointing out that `@RequestParam` is not needed here! Thought, it's kind of a mapping between the URL parameters and JPA entity atttributes that is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If [spring-data-rest projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) is fine
instead of JPA projection

try

- moving the `DataView` interface class to the same package where the `Data` entity is located
- and add the following annotation on top of the `DataView` class
  `@Projection(name = "dataView", types = Data.class)`
- then add the `?projection=dataView` query param to your search url

for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/data/search/findByLocation?location=someplace&projection=dataView
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work returning a `Collection` or `List` in query method. Same error as before: `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Couldn't find PersistentEntity for type class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121!`

Comment: I tried it with spring-boot-starter-data-rest 2.5.6 and it did work. I do see this issue for earlier version though: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/issues/1597

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a new approach to find a solution to minimize the JSON response data of an HTTP request. The key word is [Cache requests](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching-requests). It's not fixing my requested question but solved the general issue I have.

Right now, I'm caching nothing in my web app. So, for every change of navigation that causes an HTTP request, it asks the backend for data. Kind of bad behaviour.

That should be a good solution avoiding 95% of network traffic. Pretty stupid when I rethink my previous approach to just responding a subset of attributes from an entity... :)